pd.to_datetime() with the same arguments returns error when Pandas is updated from 1.5.3 to 2.2.2. What exactly changed?
I'm trying to convert the contents of a str timestamp column to datetime. The input timestamp string differs from the STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT, but Pandas 1.5.3 is able to do the conversion just fine:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'timestamp': [
        '2024-05-02 10:00:00.000000+0000',
        '2024-05-02 10:00:01.000000+0000',
        '2024-05-02 10:00:02.000000+0000',
        '2024-05-02 10:00:03.000000+0000',
        '2024-05-02 10:00:04.000000+0000'
    ],
    'value': [False, False, False, False, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format=STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT)

In our code, we were using Pandas 1.5.3 with Python 3.8, but now we're updating to 2.2.2 with Python 3.12.
With 1.5.3 + Python 3.8, there seems to be some kind of format auto detecting, even though it's not being explicited in the function arguments.
With 2.2.2 + Python 3.12, I get the following error from the code snippet above:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format=STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT)

File ~/tmp/test-pandas/.venv3_12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py:1067, in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
   1065         result = arg.map(cache_array)
   1066     else:
-> 1067         values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
   1068         result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
   1069 elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

File ~/tmp/test-pandas/.venv3_12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py:433, in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, utc, unit, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    431 # `format` could be inferred, or user didn't ask for mixed-format parsing.
    432 if format is not None and format != "mixed":
--> 433     return _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, utc, format, exact, errors)
    435 result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64(
    436     arg,
    437     dayfirst=dayfirst,
   (...)
    441     allow_object=True,
    442 )
    444 if tz_parsed is not None:
    445     # We can take a shortcut since the datetime64 numpy array
    446     # is in UTC

File ~/tmp/test-pandas/.venv3_12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py:467, in _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, utc, fmt, exact, errors)
    456 def _array_strptime_with_fallback(
    457     arg,
    458     name,
   (...)
    462     errors: str,
    463 ) -> Index:
    464     """
    465     Call array_strptime, with fallback behavior depending on 'errors'.
    466     """
--> 467     result, tz_out = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors, utc=utc)
    468     if tz_out is not None:
    469         unit = np.datetime_data(result.dtype)[0]

File strptime.pyx:501, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

File strptime.pyx:451, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

File strptime.pyx:587, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime._parse_with_format()

ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S": ".000000+0000", at position 0. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

In 2.2.2 + Python 3.12, in order for this to work I need to fix STANDARD_DATETIME_FORMAT to match the input timestamp str.
I went on to read the function reference documentation but, in 1.5.3, all parameters that would somehow affect this outcome are all correctly set by default already: exact=True and infer_datetime_format=False.
I'll be fixing the format, but I'd like to know exactly what changed from 1.5.3 to 2.x.x in this aspect.

If the format is relatively standard, just don't specify it, pandas will autodetect it

'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z' You have to specify the milliseconds(.%f) and the UTC offset +00000(%z).
